# How do I assign an entity key of entity as a property of different entity in datastore (Node JS)?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working a really basic REST API in Node js. I have a 'boat' entity and a 'slip' entity. I want to assign a boat's entity key as the value of the slip's boat property. Essentially a foreign key situation here.

I have a feeling I will need to look more into the child/parent entity structure for a solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For parent/child relations you will need to create keys like that.

```
db.save({
    //this key is incomplete, so database will automatically assign id for
    //the child entity. Parent entity uses user provided name.
    key: db.key(["ParentEntityKind", "1234", "ChildEntityKind"]),
    data: { someData: 1 }
});
```

To store key as a property in other entity just pass as a data key object.
Note, that key that will be stored as a property should be completed, that means it should has name or id at the end of it's path.

```
let keyToBeStored = db.key(["KindName", "123"]);
let keyFromAlreadyCreatedObject = obj[db.KEY];

db.save({
    key: db.key(["SomeKindThatStoresKeysAsProperty"]),
    data: {
        keyCreatedInCodeRef: keyToBeStored,
        keyFromObjectRef: keyFromAlreadyCreatedObject
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. Is the keyToBeStored the appropriate argument in the following query filter:  .filter('_ _key_ _', '=', keyToBeStored)

Comment: Discovered that the results of a query are within a nested array.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. And, yes, answering on you first comment question, you can pass key object into filter and anywhere you want, it will behave correctly.